# Xcode debugger problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, step-into

I'm trying to debug my code with the help of the debugger in Xcode, but when I'm trying to step in, nothing is happening. I tried it with another project and it's debugging fine there.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times xCode takes much time to calculate data, so its just shows stepping over.
In this situation you can NSLog your values to debug.